# Android Studio looking for AndroidManifest.xml in wrong folder

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am having an issue where a project I have downloaded from a local git repo is not compiling for me.

The errors I am getting are

```
GradeExemption not found
```

and more importantly:

**ERROR: Cannot read packageName from `D:\Source Code\The Project - Android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`**

However, the AndroidManifest is located at `D:\Source Code\The Project - Android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` and I am not sure how to make the solution see that.
I have checked The Project - Android.iml file, and it has:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module external.linked.project.id=":" external.linked.project.path="D:\Source Code\The Project - Android" external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.system.id="GRADLE" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="android-gradle" name="Android-Gradle">
      <configuration>
        <option name="GRADLE_PROJECT_PATH" value=":" />
        <option name="LAST_SUCCESSFUL_SYNC_AGP_VERSION" />
        <option name="LAST_KNOWN_AGP_VERSION" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$" />
    <orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="1.8" jdkType="JavaSDK" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>
```

If you need it, my Android Studio version is 3.5.1, Grade model version is 4.1, and NDK version is UNKNOWN.

I have tried to open the project, import the project, re-downloaded it from the SVN, reinstalled Android Studio, and invalidated the cache.

I have "fixed" the `GradleException` not found error by replacing `GradleException` with `FileNotFoundException`, but do you have any ideas on how to resolve the `AndroidManifest.xml` issue?

EDIT:
As requested, the manifest.xml app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.foo.theproject">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:name="com.foo.base.cmApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/dvw_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="2cec7d652dd91e36e052e9cbee7cf8d215043ad2" />

        <activity
            android:name=".TaskView"
            android:label="DVW"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TabletLayoutActivity"
            android:label="DVW"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PhoneLayoutActivity"
            android:label="DVW"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <!--<activity-->
            <!--android:name=".MainActivity"-->
            <!--android:label="DVW"-->
            <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>-->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT 2:
Global build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
    compile 'com.kyanogen.signatureview:signature-view:1.1@aar'
    compile files('libs/FlexiCoreProvider-1.7p7.signed.jar')
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }
    //compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
}
```

the /app build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

def baseVersion = "2.6."

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        Properties versionProps = new Properties()
        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
        def code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger() + 1

        versionProps['VERSION_CODE'] = code.toString()
        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.dryerventwizard.techwizard"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode code
            versionName baseVersion + code
        }
    } else {
        //throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') { transitive = true; }
    compile project(':..:LMBoot:lmboot')
}

gradle.buildFinished {
    buildResult ->
        println ""
        println "BUILD FINISHED"
        println ""

        def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
        if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
            Properties versionProps = new Properties()
            versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
            def code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger()
            println("Version " + baseVersion + code.toString())
        }
}
```

EDIT 3:
Tried to sync with file stream, and sync with gradle, no change.
ReplacedcompileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:26' with compileSdkVersion 26 to clear the cannot find 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:26' error.

EDIT 4:
If I include the app in `manifest.srcFile app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, it looks for the xml file in `app/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.
If I remove the app, it looks for the file in `/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: can you post your manifest.xml file too ?

Comment: You don't say what OS you are using on your build machine, but spaces in `PATH` names is a **bad** idea e.g. `D:\Source Code\The Project`.

Comment: @JonGoodwin, I know, however, it was that way since before the project fell into my lap.  Not something I can change.

Comment: It's **NOT** optional ! I guess your using Windows ?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10.

Comment: @GokuMizuno Can you also attach the build gradle file of the app ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the File->Sync Project with Gradle files.

Comment: Tried that, no change, sadly.